# Finer control over units in nautilus size column

Tags: nautilus

Is there a way to configure nautilus so that the size all used the same unit, say kB or MB, rather than varying units?  I find it hard to see, at a glance, the relative sizes of things when the units are changing all the time - especially when I have the view sorting on some other column.

Also, is it possible to have folders to list the recursive size contained inside, rather than just saying "5 items" or similar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible without modifying Nautilus sources (see **update** below)

However, there's an awesome tool included with Ubuntu which would help you to visualize relative sizes of files and folders. The program is called Baobab a.k.a. Disk Usage Analyzer and I believe it is installed by default:

[image: baobab]

**Update:** Out of curiosity, I downloaded Nautilus sources and spent a few minutes browsing around trying to see how it is formatting file sizes. Indeed, in `nautilus-file.c` there's a function:

```
static char *
nautilus_file_get_size_as_string (NautilusFile *file)
{
    ...        
    if (nautilus_file_is_directory (file)) {
        ...
        return format_item_count_for_display (item_count, TRUE, TRUE);
    }
    ...
    return g_format_size (file->details->size);
}
```

And if you check the [documentation for g_format_size](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.29/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-format-size), it says

> Sizes are rounded to the nearest size prefix (kB, MB, GB) and are
>   displayed rounded to the nearest tenth.

So, as you can see, Nautilus is hard-coded to display items count for directories and file sizes rounded to the nearest prefix for files.

(as a side note - if you try Baobab, you'll see that scanning the full disk takes quite some time. This explains why it would be impractical to display cumulative directory sizes in Nautilus - this would slow down the whole thing quite a lot)